# How to configure an brand new windows 7/8 for digital signage/infoscreen/infoterminal usage?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, google-chrome, permissions

The point is: I'm using windows mainly as an end-user - not as developer.

Our software was been developed for an micro-pc that runs OS X or a small Debian. Due missing drivers we have to switch to windows.

Now the main thing: I saw so much Infoscreens that: have bluescreens, an windows error prompt over their software or some popus - or even worse the user got in the actual windows system.

Our software is an webapp that runs in Google Chrome Kiosk Mode (autostart with a link) – The users can also use the touchscreen, but have no keyboard.

---

So are there any ready to use utils to fix all that?

We are familiar with Windows but mainly develop things on *nix-sytems.

Comment: There are dozens of application packages designed to make a PC into a kiosk I suggest you use one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several programs which offer features to lock down a computer to use it as a public kiosk or digital signage system. Also take into account that Windows 8.1 offers a [kiosk mode (assigned access feature)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160224035442/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/hyperyash/archive/2013/10/25/enable-kiosk-mode-in-windows-8-1.aspx).

Some program examples:

- [Secure Lockdown](https://web.archive.org/web/20160624125032/http://shop.inteset.com:80/lock-down-windows-with-inteset-secure-lockdown) by Inteset.
- [FrontFace Lockdown Tool](https://www.mirabyte.com/en/frontface/lockdown-tool/features.html) by Mirabyte.
- [Public Kiosk Software](https://www.fkeysolutions.com/public-kiosk-software.html) by F Key Solutions Inc. (last updated on 2012).
- [Advanced Internet Kiosk](https://www.softstack.com/advink.html) sold by SoftStack, being a more updated version of Public Kiosk Software by F Key Solutions Inc.
- [SiteKiosk Windows](https://www.provisio.com/web/es/productos/sitekiosk-windows) by Provisio.
- [Fortres 101](https://www.fortresgrand.com/products/f101/f101.htm) by Fortres Grand (need to be purchased to try it).
- [AlwaysUp](https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/) by Core Technologies.
- [Secure Desktop](https://www.visualautomation.com/securedesktop/) by Visual Automation.
- [Webconverger](https://webconverger.com/), an open source operating system made for kiosk computers.

This can be a starting point to the OP.

In order to perform a quick test, we used [Gmail Notifier Pro](http://www.gmailnotifier.se/) to create pop-ups on a Windows 7 machine and checked if the program blocked the pop-up.
So far the following programs didn't block the pop-up: [Secure Lockdown](https://web.archive.org/web/20160624125032/http://shop.inteset.com:80/lock-down-windows-with-inteset-secure-lockdown), [FrontFace Lockdown Tool](https://www.mirabyte.com/en/frontface/lockdown-tool/features.html), [AlwaysUp](https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/).
Nonetheless, [Advanced Internet Kiosk](https://www.softstack.com/advink.html) blocked it.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide more than just a link, for example some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: Done, we've performed some tests and added more information.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. I just forget to give you the green check.